# hibernate - how to change properties at runtime

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I am trying to change properties in hibernate.cfg.xml but my code doesn't work.

```
public static void changeConfiguration(String login, String password){
    Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
    cfg.configure();
    cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", password);
    cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", login); 

}
```

Any idea why thats doesnt work? My file hibernate.cfg.xml always looks the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make it work, you should build your `sessionFactory` with that `Configuration` object and then use that `sessionFactory` to get  your session.

Something like :

```
public static SessionFactory changeConfiguration(String login, String password){
    Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
    cfg.configure();
    cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", password);
    cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", login); 
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

But at the end, it will not change the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file, it overwrite or defines properties at runtime. If you don't want to put your username and password in the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file, you should probably use a `.properties` file that contain these values.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the configuration will update the configuration that has been read in memory from the configuration file. It won't update the file itself (which, most of the time, is read-only since read from a war or jar file).